# How to build structure with different set of column names?

Tags: coldfusion, structure, coldfusion-9, cfloop

I have two different set of columns in my cfquery. One set of columns is reserved for the `values` and second is reserved for `title` in the form input fields. I'm building structure on the server side and I would like these two in separate columns. Here is example:

```
<cfquery name="UInfo" datasource="Test">
    SELECT TOP 1
        u_fname,
        u_lname,
        zu_fname,
        zu_lname
    FROM Users WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE u_urid = '0012341'
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="UInfo">
    <cfset qryRecs = StructNew()>
    <cfloop array="#UInfo.getColumnNames()#" index="columnName">
        <cfset qryRecs[columnName]['value'] = UInfo[columnName][CurrentRow]>
        <cfset qryRecs[columnName]['title'] = (structKeyExists(UInfo, "z"&columnName)? UInfo[columnName][CurrentRow] : "")>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

My code above will produce this kind of output:

```
U_FNAME     
struct
title   First Time
value   Mark
U_FLAST     
struct
title   New Customer
value   Miller
ZU_FNAME    
struct
title   First Time
value   [empty string]
ZU_LNAME    
struct
title   New Customer
value   [empty string]
```

As you can see above my code produced structure for Z columns as well. I don't need separate structure for these columns they should show in TITLE only. My output should be something like this:

```
U_FNAME     
struct
    title   First Time
    value   Mark
U_FLAST     
struct
    title   New Customer
    value   Miller
```

I'm not sure how to get desired output. If anyone can help please elt me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears you simply need an if statement on the columnName inside the column names loop

```
<cfif left(columnName, 1) eq "u">
```

Comment: I found solution as well. Only difference is that I used Find("u",columNames,0) to check if first letter is U. I'm not sure if this solution can cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
<cfset qryRecs = StructNew()>
```

inside a loop.  It should be before this:

```
<cfloop query="UInfo">
```

Comment: Good catch. Do you have any suggestion for my problem above? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you were looking to achieve or why you want to achieve it, so I don't have any other suggestions.